# ZOHO smtp SMTPAuthenticationError at / (535, 'Authentication Failed') Django app

Tags: django, smtp, zoho

I am trying to establish a connection via shell on the VPS with this code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


sender = 'my zoho email'
recipient = 'my gmail account email'


msg = MIMEText("Message text")
msg['Subject'] = "Sent from python"
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = recipient


server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.zoho.com', 465)

# Perform operations via server
server.login('my zoho account email', '*********')
```

All the credentials are correct, since I am login in successfully to my account at https://www.zoho.eu/mail/

When i try to login with:

```
server.login('my zoho account email', '*********')
```

I get SMTPAuthenticationError and the stack trace shows:

```
 self.connection.login(force_str(self.username), force_str(self.password)) 
 ...
 raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
```

my settings.py is:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'     
EMAIL_USE_TSL = True
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.zoho.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '**********'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*********'
```

There are numerous threads about this on the web but, not even one has an answer about it. Their support doesn't answer for third day now...

I am using NGINX and the default configuration is not set for https:// but my custom configuration is and the website is running over https://.

Edit: If I try to connect over port 587 with:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.zoho.com', 587)
```

I get:

```
SSLError: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:590)
```

Comment: I hope that you checked the passwords.

Comment: Make sure you don't have 2-steps authentication enabled.

Comment: I am using the same passwords that I am loggin in their web site. That should be correct. I changed the password twice already.

Comment: @MuhammadAsif I don't have it enabled.

Comment: @HenryLynx 587 is never gonna work with SSL. As per Zoho mail's docs, 587 uses tls. I'd suggest you to send emails with tls on 587 encryption rather than SSL on 465

Comment: @HenryLynx change this line server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.zoho.com', 465) to server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.zoho.com', 587) and then add this line smtplib.starttls() .... After that

Comment: Also update in Email Backend

Comment: server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,587)
server.ehlo()
s.starttls()
s.login(smtp_user,smtp_pass)
s.sendmail(sender, recp, msg.as_string())
s.quit()

Comment: @HenryLynx your could should look like this

Comment: @MuhammadAsif I tried it like you said and now I am getting more verbose response: SMTPSenderRefused: (530, '5.5.1 Authentication Required.', 'admin@maet.bg')

Comment: Now I saw that I don't have DKIM - DomainKeys Identified Mail activated so I will look into this now.

Comment: Ok. Let us know if it works

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out I was registered under the European host of zoho so I fixed it by changing the EMAIL_HOST to 'smtp.zoho.eu'

Comment: imagine spending several hours over this, you're a life saver thank you.

Comment: oh my god! you are a lifesaver, i couldn't figure this out for the past 2 months and i contacted namecheap because i thought they have some problem from their side.

Comment: How did you find that you are registered with European host of zoho ?

Comment: in my case it was `smtp.zoho.in`

Answer (score 2):

This is the only setting I have in settings.py and it is enough to get it working.

```
#Email Settings
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.zoho.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'someone@example.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'yourpassword'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'someone@example.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'someone@example.com'
```

You can test it using the quick example from [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#quick-example).

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

[image]

Comment: SERVER_EMAIL was what was missing in my `settings.py`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had to add ignoreTLS to work

```
const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.zoho.eu",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: config.ZOHO_USER,
        pass: config.ZOHO_PASS
    },
    ignoreTLS: true // <----
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've already got this solved, but I was having this same error and figured out that the solution was that I had recently enabled 2FA on the account, so I had to add an App Specific Password.

Instructions for doing this can be found in the [Zoho Mail docs](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/adminconsole/two-factor-authentication.html#alink5).