# Use email created on cpanel to send message in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, namecheap

i try to make setting for send message to user when they create account or rest password ( i use all auth ) ,, but when try to create acc to ex the page just still loading , it don't do anything
how to fix it

```
# email message send
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST= 'mail.filltasks.live'
EMAIL_HOST_USER= 'no-reply@filltasks.live'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD= 'mypass_namecheap_acc'
EMAIL_USE_TLS= True
EMAIL_PORT= 465

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

---

> **edit it do that and worked fine !!!!**

---

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.yourdomain' # for ex ,, mail.site.com
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'no-reply@filltasks.live'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ' the password for your email not your account' 
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

thanks for

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48750034/19161837

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.yourdomain' # for ex ,, mail.site.com
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'no-reply@filltasks.live'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ' the password for your email not your account' 
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

thanks for

[best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483015/sending-godaddy-email-via-django-using-python/48750034#48750034)