# How to setup flask mail with zoho mail

Tags: python, zoho, flask-mail

I have tried what I can think of but can't get the email to be sent from my application using flask-mail with Zoho mail.

I've tried setting up an app password and I have tried the following examples of configuration using some of the information from their site:

https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/pop-access.html

```
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.zoho.com' 
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465 
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True 
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = '_@whatever.com' 
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'

app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.zoho.com' 
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 587 
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = True 
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = '__@whatever.com' 
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'XXXXXXXXXXX'
```

I would expect to be able to send an email using flask-mail with my custom domain which is setup with zoho.

Comment: Please explain what goes wrong in which setup you tried. Otherwise, all you could hope for are general pointers to instructions for setting up these packages.

Comment: After submitting the webform to send the email I get an authentication error. I'm guessing it's something I'm doing wrong with zoho mail, and would really like some general pointers on setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

Check which host of Zoho you are registered with, if you are based in Europe you will have to edit the MAIL_SEVER parameter to:

```
app.config['MAIL_SERVER']  = 'smtp.zoho.eu'
```

This should solve the SMTPAuthenticationError.

Similar question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45324416/zoho-smtp-smtpauthenticationerror-at-535-authentication-failed-django-app)

Answer (score 0):

For secure access head on to general setting on Zoho mail(https://mail.zoho.com/zm/#settings/general)
[My account>Security Questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhMzz.png)

[Application-Specific Passwords > Generate new password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J94on.png)
name your app. It'll give you a password

```
export MAIL_PASSWORD=<generated-password>
```

then in config.py

```
import os
MAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('MAIL_PASSWORD')
```

And when you use TLS Zoho on time of writing this uses the port 587\